# how to search a document containing a substring

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have the following document with this (partial) mapping:

```
  "message": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm trying to perform a query for document containing `"success":"0"` through the following DSL query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "regexp": {
          "message": ".*\"success\".*0.*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't get any result, whereas if I perform the following DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "regexp": {
          "message": ".*\"success\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm returned some document! I.e.

```
{"data":"[{\"appVersion\":\"1.1.1\",\"installationId\":\"any-ubst-id\",\"platform\":\"aaa\",\"brand\":\"Dalvik\",\"screenSize\":\"xhdpi\"}]","executionTime":"0","flags":"0","method":"aaa","service":"myService","success":"0","type":"aservice","version":"1"}
```

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: I'm curious why you decided to index the JSON content in your `data` field as text instead of an object?

Answer (score 1):

The text field `message` uses standard analyzer which tokenize the input string and convert it to tokens.

If we analyze the string `"success":"0"` using standard analyzer we will get these tokens

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "success",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "0",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So you can see that colon double quotes etc are removed. And since regexp query applied on each token it will not match your query.

But if we use `message.keyword` which has field type keyword. it is not analyzed thus keep the string as it is.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": """ "success":"0" """,
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

So if we use the below query it should work

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": """.*"success".*0.*"""
    }
  }
}
```

But another problem is you have set `message.keyword` field settings to `"ignore_above": 256` So This field will ignore any string longer than 256 characters.